# Oracle SQL: how do I list the fields if it's not a date?

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle SQL: how do I list the fields if it's not a date?

select colA, colB, ColC, ColD
from table
where not isdate(ColC)

But it's giving me errors, I'm not sure how I can repharse it.....

Comment: You cannot control the select list itself in this way without using dynamic SQL.  Why do you have the situation where you don't the types of the columns in your database table?

Comment: oh, the column is date formatted; I just thought it would be good to run a quick sql check on it.

Comment: could u show me how to do it in dynamic sql? thanks,

Comment: Column is varchar and you have the data in date format?? If yes, then what is the format in which you have the date string in column?

Comment: what version is your database?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [VALIDATE_CONVERSION](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html) function introduced in Oracle Database 12.2.  You can put `WHERE VALIDATE_CONVERSION(...) = 0` to find any value that isn't a date.

```
WITH
    sample_data
    AS
        (SELECT '2020-01-01' AS val FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '2020-02-01' AS val FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'text' AS val FROM DUAL)
SELECT val, validate_conversion (val AS DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS isdate
  FROM sample_data;


          VAL    ISDATE
_____________ _________
2020-01-01            1
2020-02-01            1
text                  0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use to_date() to validate a Date in oracle. Write a function which will take a date as string and format and return true or false:

```
  create or replace function isdate
     ( p_string in varchar2,
         p_fmt in varchar2 := null)
          return varchar2
        as
            l_date date;
        begin
            l_date :=
         to_date(p_string,p_fmt);
         return 'TRUE';
       exception
           when others then
               return 'FALSE';
       end;

   select isdate('1 jan 2021','dd mm yyyy') IsValidDate from dual;
   select isdate('1 jan1 2021','dd mm yyyy')IsValidDate from dual;
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: How would you use the `isdate` function in the WHERE clause of a SELECT query?